# how to deep _sumBy using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
var data= [{
        "item_name": "Jumbo Combo",
        "item_key": "9lazhy15tp2fgo72",
        "item_price": 25,
        "quantity": 1,
        "ingredients": [{
            "group_key": "fg1udvnz81qwpxtp",
            "key": "kcck54k7h3fzp5f0",
            "ingredient_name": "Large",
            "price": 3
        }]
    }, {
        "item_name": "Swiss & Mushroom Combo",
        "item_key": "e1vdfos6s50d5kej",
        "item_price": 22,
        "quantity": 1,
        "ingredients": [{
            "group_key": "fg1udvnz81qwpxtp",
            "key": "kcck54k7h3fzp5f0",
            "ingredient_name": "Large",
            "price": 3
        }]
    }]
```

i want to sum the `item_price` as well as `"ingredients":[{"price":3}]` using loadash how to deep sumBy

i tryed item_price

```
_.sumBy(data, 'item_price')
```

this can get the total price of item price in an array, but how to get sum of price of `ingredients and item_price`

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply by quantity? Furthermore I do not get why you want to sum over ingredients as well, since ususally the cost of an item is the cost of the ingredients plus something extra.

Comment: exactly i want to sum item price with ingredients then multiply with quantity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sum of elements with the price of the ingredients

Besides passing the name of an attribute as a string to the [**`_sumBy`**](https://lodash.com/docs#sumBy) function, you can also pass a function that determines what function to apply the items to obtain values that can be summed up. So we can replace the query with:

```
_.sumBy(data, x => x.item_price)
```

But now we still need to sum up the ingredients. How will we do that? Use another `_.sumBy` of course!

```
_.sumBy(data, x => x.item_price + _.sumBy(x.ingredients, 'price'))
```

(this yields `53`).

## Multiply with the quantity

We can immediately multiply these values with the `quantity` attribute as well:

```
_.sumBy(data, x => x.quantity * (x.item_price + _.sumBy(x.ingredients, 'price')))
```

(this yields again `53`, since all quantities are 1).

Answer (score 1):

[`Lodash#SumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sumBy) can take a function as second argument. You can use it to access the `ingredients` of each items and use `SumBy` once again.

```js
const data = [{ item_name: 'Jumbo Combo', item_price: 25, item_key: '9lazhy15tp2fgo72', quantity: 1, ingredients: [{ group_key: 'fg1udvnz81qwpxtp', key: 'kcck54k7h3fzp5f0', ingredient_name: 'Large', price: 3 }]}, { item_name: 'Swiss & Mushroom Combo', item_key: 'e1vdfos6s50d5kej', item_price: 22, quantity: 1, ingredients: [{ group_key: 'fg1udvnz81qwpxtp', key: 'kcck54k7h3fzp5f0', ingredient_name: 'Large', price: 3 }]}];

const sum = _.sumBy(data, item => item.item_price + _.sumBy(item.ingredients, 'price'));

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```